# How can I concatenate strings inside a TSQL command?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How can I concatenate strings embedded in a TSQL statement?

```
DECLARE @db NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @backupFile NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @db = N'Test';
SET @backupFile = N'D:\Temp\' + @db + N'.bak';

/* This works */
BACKUP DATABASE @db TO DISK = @backupFile WITH INIT, SKIP, CHECKSUM;

/* This does not work - Incorrect syntax */
BACKUP DATABASE @db TO DISK = N'D:\Temp\' + @db + N'.bak' WITH INIT, SKIP, CHECKSUM;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use expressions to replace something that needs to be a literal or variable. For the same reason that something like `EXEC sys.sp_executesql N'SELECT * FROM ' + @TableName;` would fail. The variable has to contain the full value.

This is demonstrated in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/backup-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) which shows that `DISK`'s value must be `{ logical_device_name | @logical_device_name_var }`. So the input value for `DISK` *must* be either the logical device's name or a variable containing the value of the logical device. It *cannot* be an expression, as that isn't valid syntax.

Syntax that does allow such syntax (to use expressions as well as literals and variables) are clearly documented to do so too. For example [`CONVERT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)'s syntax is as follows:

```
CONVERT ( data_type [ ( length ) ] , expression [ , style ] )
```

Notice that it's simply `expression` for the second parameter; so this could be a literal, a variable, a mix of both, it doesn't matter.

The key is that the value must be a literal or variable for the value of `DISK` here.

If you *really* wanted to use an expression, rather than a variable, you would have to use dynamic SQL, (which I demonstrated in my [deleted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66901163/2029983) when I initially misunderstood the question), but I see no need for it here, as parametrisation is far better.